# Program execution of a 64 bit hypothetical machine

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

1. I was asked to design a 64 bit hypothetical machine , i have decided 
   to put 4 bit as opcode and the rest 60 bits as address because the 
   question only wants me to perform 2 operations which are addition of 3 
   integers and multiplication of 2 integers so a 4 bit instruction would 
   be sufficient. Heres the thing , i have to design the program 
   execution. If i were to use a 60 bit address , it would mean i will 
   have a 15 digit hex of address , is this the only way? can someone show 
   me how to design it without having so many digits of address because my 
   design would be very messy. The first image is the questions , second 
   is the one i attempted doing, those are some of the instructions i gave 
   , third is the image of a 16 bit machine . is it suppose to turn out 
   this way? because it is really messy. Im suppose to draw the machine 
   out like the second picture , just different instruction and 
   arithmetics equations.

   [image: First image]
   [image: Fourth image]

Comment: Please write your code and show your approach to the people first.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Comment: Most 64-bit RISC CPUs use 32-bit instruction words.  Look at DEC Alpha AXP, for example, which was designed to be 64-bit from the ground up (unlike MIPS64 or others that extended an existing 32-bit architecture).  No point spending twice as much I-cache on having giant instruction words unless you want to pack a lot into each instruction.  (e.g. ARM has predicated execution, MIPS has large-ish immediates and 32 registers, PowerPC has a lot of opcodes, and those are all still 32-bit instruction width.)   Anyway, I don't know what you mean with the rest of the instruction being one huge address.

Answer (score 1):

The hypothetical "16-bit machine" (shown in the third picture) has 12-bit addresses, 16-bit registers, and 16-bit instructions. Since it only has an single register (AC) that holds operands for instructions, it is described as an [accumulator machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulator_(computing)). Let's start from it to design a hypothetical "64-bit machine".

> i have decided to put 4 bit as opcode and the rest 60 bits as address
>   because the question only wants me to perform 2 operations which are
>   addition of 3 integers and multiplication of 2 integers so a 4 bit
>   instruction would be sufficient.

The question requires listing at least eight instructions, therefore the size of the opcode field has to be at least three bits.

> Heres the thing , i have to design the program execution. If i were to
>   use a 60 bit address , it would mean i will have a 15 digit hex of
>   address , is this the only way?

There is really no restriction on the maximum size of the opcode, or the size of an instruction for that matter. For example, let's use fixed-size instructions that are 64-bit in size, allocate the least significant 8 bits for the opcode, leaving the remaining 56 bits to hold an address. Although you could define as much as 2^8 = 256 opcodes, you only need to define 8. The rest can be left as "reserved" for future use to add new instructions. You don't have to say anything about them.

> can someone show me how to design it without having so many digits of
>   address because my design would be very messy

You don't have to use such large addresses. You can use small addresses, such as 0x300, and leave the non-significant zeros implicit (or write them explicitly in the first address only).

> second is the one i attempted doing, those are some of the
>   instructions i gave

Keep in mind that you have two locations that can be used as sources of destinations of instructions; the 64-bit AC register and the 64-bit memory location addressed by the 56-bit address.

First, you don't technically need instructions that can do addition or multiplication because these can be implemented using other instructions. At the same time, there is no need to make the design unnecessarily complicated, so you can just go ahead and define an addition instruction and a multiplication instruction. You need also two instructions to load and store from/to memory to/from the AC register. That's a total of 4 instructions so far. You still need at least 4 more.

The "execution of program terminates" instruction is necessary, but you can just call it "halt" or "halt execution" instead. In this instruction, the values in AC and the address field can be just ignored. The instruction that displays the contents of AC onto screen must be defined more precisely. For example, you can define it as "displays the ASCII character stored in the least significant byte of AC onto the screen." or as "displays the zero-terminated ASCII string stored in memory at the address specified the least significant 56 bits of AC onto the screen."

The I/O instructions you proposed should be accepted, but you can define more interesting instructions. The 7th instruction could be defined as "reads an ASCII character from the keyboard and stores it as the least significant byte of AC." or as "reads an ASCII character from the keyboard and stores it in memory at the address specified by AC and then increments AC by one."

The 8th instruction could be defined as "Jumps to the instruction whose address is specified in memory at the address specified by the address operand if AC is zero." Therefore, if AC is zero, the address of the new next instruction is stored in PC and the instruction is loaded into IR. This is called a control-flow instruction and it's very useful. Other instructions could be easily defined such as shift or logical instructions.

If you get rid of the I/O load and store instructions, you can omit the I/O devices state from the illustration.

I'll leave it for you to write a program that adds three integers and another program that multiplies two integers. Let me know in the comments what you come up with if you prefer.

Comment: Hi there , thanks for all the wonderful advices . I would like to ask , if i were to remove the load and store I/O instructions , should i remove my instruction that displays contents on the screen since i wont have I/O device from the illustration?

Comment: Do i need the 8th instruction because if the AC is zero , it would automatically go to the instruction in a specific address

Comment: if i remove I/O devices , how can i show that a user keyed in an ASCII character like what you said?

Comment: @Jane You should choose either the load and store I/O instructions or the specialized I/O instructions (displaying on screen and reading from the keyboard), but not both. The load and store I/O instructions can be used withe any I/O device, and therefore they are more powerful, but more difficult to define. That's because you need to define the I/O address space and how I/O devices are mapped to it including the screen and the keyboard. You can show what the user keyed by writing something like "assume key 'a' was pressed" in some suitable place in the illustration.

Comment: @Jane If AC is zero, why would control automatically transfer to the instruction in the specified address? By default, always the next contiguous instruction is executed no matter what the value in AC is. A jump instruction enables you to modify this behavior so you can support constructs such as loops.

Comment: @Jane You can edit the question and put it there, or you can upload it to some cloud storage service and post the link in a comment.

Comment: A conditional branch only for 0 / non-zero is very weak.  Unless you have an arithmetic shift instruction as well, evaluating `a < b` might require looping over the range from `0` to `a` and checking each value separately for equality to `b`.  i.e. another useful instruction would be branch on `AC > 0` (signed), or (like MIPS) some `set` instructions that replace AC with a 0 / 1 boolean compare result, so you can do unsigned compare for `<` (which requires carry-out from the top bit of a subtract).

Comment: And BTW, a direct branch (which sets PC = immediate address encoded in the instruction, or adds it as a relative offset.  Again MIPS is neat...) would be nice to have so you don't need pointers in memory for use with indirect branches.  (Maybe with a built-in left shift if instruction addresses must be aligned) instead of loading, to encode more address space).  But if you want to keep the ISA simple at the expense of clunky programs, then only provide indirect branches; you can build direct branches out of indirect, but building indirect branches from direct would require self-modifying code.

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed. I'm thinking of how to evaluate `a < b` using only the 8 instruction defined in my answer (although the addition and multiplication instructions need to be defined more precisely). This sounds like a good mental exercise. I'm thinking of adding `-1` to each of `a` and `b` until at least one of them becomes zero. The one that becomes zero first is the smaller. If both became zero together, then they are equal. The `jump` instruction enables us to test for zero in AC. The time complexity of this algorithm is theta(min(a, b)). Not sure whether there is a faster algorithm.

Comment: I only used 4 instructions instead of 8 .. but i got the addition and multiplication out

Comment: @Jane Can you generate a link with read-only open access? So that anyone can see it without having to request for permission, and potentially get feedback from multiple people. You can delete the file later.

Comment: @Jane Well, I don't know the encoding of the instructions, what's supposed to happen at each step, and what the arrows mean.

Comment: If you have shifts, you can extract ranges of bits (or single bits) `x >> 63`, or `(x << 1) >> 63`.  I think you can do `a<b` (signed or unsigned) in O(log2(64)) time, i.e. O(1) time with shifts, bypassing the need for the carry-out of a subtraction result.  You can find out if two numbers are in the same half of the range by checking the top bit (compare for equality with a subtract).  If they're not, check which one is in the higher half (check that bit in one of them for 0).  Repeat for lower bits in order from high to low.

Comment: And BTW, my previous idea about arithmetic right shift was bogus.  Signed and unsigned compare based on a subtraction result both still need the carry-out (65th bit).  But with an arithmetic shift, you can use that to check all the rest of the bits after checking if the numbers are in the same half of the range or not.  `(a-b) >> 63` (arithmetic shift) is 0 or -1 (2's complement) depending on the sign of the result.  i.e. use `>>` to broadcast the sign bit.  Wait a minute, we don't need to broadcast, even a logical right shift works.

Comment: thats the updated diagram , and a step by step explanation , i only used 4 instructions

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah it seems to me without shift or subtraction (or negation) instructions, we cannot do better than theta(min(a, b)), which is actually very expensive. Although if we choose a different set of 8 instructions, we might be able to do a<b much more efficiently, but probably sacrificing the efficiency of other operations.

Comment: I forget we only had ADD, not SUB or NEG.  Limiting this to 8 instructions seems pretty arbitrary and very limiting; probably better to have SUB than MUL for general use.  An accumulator machine with absolute memory operands  encoded in every instruction seems pretty crap; hard to implement pointers with no address register.  It doesn't make any sense to me to spend transistors building a machine with huge 64-bit instruction words and a giant address space instead of spending them on a more complex instruction format or at least some indirect load / store instructions.

Comment: Basically, there's a reason everything is a register machine these days, even if most ALU instructions can only use a single accumulator and there's only one or two pointer registers.

Comment: @Jane Looks good. It's important to explicitly state the two assumptions being made here. First, all addresses are 60-bit in size and all values are 64-bit in size, but you're omitting the non-significant zeros. Second, the machine is assumed to be 64-bit addressable, not byte addressable. That is, 0x300 points to a 64-bit chunk and 0x301 points to the next 64-bit chunk in memory. You have a typo in step 2, "js". Also, you should probably write the program being executed as a sequence of instructions in terms of the 8 instructions defined above.

Comment: @PeterCordes Agreed.

Comment: "Also, you should probably write the program being executed as a sequence of instructions in terms of the 8 instructions defined above , what do u mean by this ?"do u mean i should include all 8 instructions instead of 4 hahaha .

Comment: @Jane Steps 1 and 2 execute the `load 940` instruction, steps 3 and 4 execute the `add 941` instruction, steps 5 and 6 execute the `add 942` instruction, steps 7 and 8 execute the `store 941` instruction, steps 9 and 10 execute the `load 940` instruction, and steps 11 and 12 execute the `mul 941` instruction. Hence, the program being executed is `load 940; add 941; add 942; store 941; load 940; mul 941` where the address of the first instruction is 300. Also it seems to me that all the values are in decimal, not hexadecimal. You should mention that at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: got it thank you so much . So i just state at the beginning saying that i removed all the significant zeros in the 60 bits address?

Comment: @Jane Yes, but only from the illustration. They are still there stored in memory and occupy space. You're just not explicitly showing them. I guess you mean the non-significant zeros.

Comment: @Jane If this answers your question, you can click on the check mark below the upvote/downvote buttons to accept the answer.